# Why replace('aaaaaaa', 'a', 'b') in SQL function does not replace all 'a' letters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having a problem with the `select replace('aaaaaaa', 'a', 'b')` in T-SQL (SQL Server 2012). I have not tried with other versions of SQL.

I epxect to get `'bbbbbbb'` but the result is `'aaaaaab'`.

When I try to test more then I have found that `replace` does not replace with `'aa'` (double 'a') but work with single 'a'.

Example:
- If I execute `replace('aa1a11a11a', 'a', 'b')` then the result is `'aa1b11b11b'` (it does not replace 'aa')

Does anybody know why is it? Is it a bug or a design feature from T-SQL?

Edited 2017.09.28:
 - Thank you all. I am clear the case now with the answer in details of Sepupic.

Comment: I can't reproduce in SQL server 2014, also not when compatibility lever is set to 110 or 100.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5eaa09/2 work as expected (SQL 2014)

Comment: Is your 'aaaaaaa' string a constant that you wrote by yourself or is it a value from some table?

Comment: I can reproduce in SQL server 2016. `select replace('aa', 'a', 'b')` produces `'aa'`, whereas `select replace('cc', 'c', 'b')` produces `'bb'` as expected. Is there something special about the letter a? Just to clarify, all the a's are the same exact character (unless my keyboard plays tricks on me).

Comment: @torbonde I've checked it and it worked (for me) on SQL Server 2016. Weird.

Comment: I think they use OTHER than 'a' characters in their strings. I want to offer the code that will show ascii code for every characters but they don't respond if that "aaa" string is a constant or goes from a table

Comment: You will need to tell us the setup of your sql instance - which I believe is going to be relevant to this question.

Comment: Just tested and it works as expected in sql server 2014 (SP2). So I cannot reproduce either

Comment: Could the varying results be related to collations?

Comment: @torbonde of course not. Are you sure you didn't copy-paste something that *looks* like an `a`?

Comment: Run `EXECUTE sp_helpsort;` on your sql instance and include the result of that in your question

Comment: Can't reproduce it either. tested on rextester and sql server 2014.

Comment: @ Richard >>> Could the varying results be related to collations?<<< No. But it could varying if the characters are not the same

Comment: @Jamiec how can it be collations if the characters are *the same*? Collations would apply if they are *not*, but look the same.

Comment: @Jamiec and of course no repro. The *same* character is the *same character* no matter the collation.

Comment: I've tried to copy-paste your `replace` statements and execute in my SQL Server. And I got the expected result. Non-reproducible.

Comment: Those who was able to reproduce, could you please execute this code: select replace(replicate('a', 10), 'a', 'b'); and show us the result as a picture?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: yes they can. Can't see why in this case (if they are all Latin lower case a) , but consider the German sharp-S when doing case conversions (in traditional orthography).

Comment: @Richard I think his point is that it is a different letter. Which is probably right.

Comment: @Richard no case conversion here. How can they anyway if it's the **same** character? I'm not talking about the same letter. The OP posted the same ASCII character here.  *Which* collation says that a character isn't equal to itself? Which treats the *ANSI* characters differently than any other?

Comment: @Rokuto: absolutely certain. I'll post a reply shortly.

Comment: @torbonde and yet, what you mentioned returns `bb`. We are talking about the ANSI `a` here, which is the same in all codepages

Comment: @torbonde Please try to exec the code that REPLICATES 'a': select replace(replicate('a', 10), 'a', 'b')

Comment: @torbonde when you post the question make sure to post the ASCII codes as well, if you want anyone to believe this

Comment: Don't you have some norwegian collation active? From wikipedia, norwegian å can be spelled as double a.

Comment: In the current closed state I cannot post this as an answer., This re-creates: `select REPLACE(replicate(char(97), 10) collate Danish_Greenlandic_100_CI_AS, 'a', 'b')` (Other collations are likely to lead to the same result, this is the first that I tried that re-created.)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Sharp-S was an *example* of where this kind of thing happens. "Which collations": two examples so far...

Comment: @Richard you was right and it is related to Danish_Norwegian collation

Comment: @Jamiec: I have run EXECUTE sp_helpsort;
the result is `Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive for Unicode Data, SQL Server Sort Order 52 on Code Page 1252 for non-Unicode Data`. I am not sure how does it help?


@Arvo, @Sepupic: yes, my database has Collation is `Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS`, it would be as you said.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace does works as you expected:

[image]

You have another problem, maybe not all your 'a' characters are 'a'? Maybe they are other symbols, for example, cyrillic 'a'?

.........................................................

I was able to reproduce it after reading comments about **Danish collation** and 'aa'.
So **Richard** was right, and here is the repro:

```
declare @t table (col varchar(100) collate Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI);
insert @t values ('aaaaaa')
select replace(col, 'a', 'b')
from @t;
```

And here is how to fix this issue:

```
declare @t table (col varchar(100) collate Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI);
insert @t values ('aaaaaa')
select replace(col collate Danish_Norwegian_BIN2, 'a', 'b')
from @t;
```

Comment: Downvoters, this is a perfectly good answer. *No repro* is perfectly valid if it's *NOT* possible to reproduce a problem. No Repro is actually a reason to *close the question*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no, if it's not reproducible, you shouldn't answer, but vote to close.

Comment: @CodeCaster sometimes a comment isn't enough to explain that something isn't reproducible. Although in this case, it seems a tutorial on ASCII and codepages might be in order

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I was able to reproduce on SQL Server 2016.

@sepupic, as per your request:
[image]

**UPDATE**
Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I'm genuinely not pulling your leg here!
[image]

Comment: No repro. What did you *actually* type? What are the ascii codes? What is your collation? 
 This returns `bbbbbbbbbb`.

Comment: Help me out here - ascii codes, what do you mean? And evidently, this doesn't return what you say it does.

Comment: I copied the query from @sepupic's comment

Comment: Try this: `SELECT ASCII ('a')` and replace this `a` with your `a`, and tell us what it returns.

Comment: What is the compatibility version and default collation of the database you are using? What is the system locale of the Windows instance SQL server is running on?

Comment: Just like everyone else, his dog and his cat, who can't reproduce this. What collation did you use? This isn't reproducible. You can find the ASCII code of a character with `ASCII('a')`. For `a`, it's 97. `A` is 65

Comment: @sepupic if there's a keyboard layout problem, or an HTML copying issue this will result in a's. On the other hand, `select replace(replicate(char(97), 10), char(97), 'b') ` should result in b's

Comment: @torbonde Norwegian collation? Where aa is å ? In this case `aa` is treated as a single character, equal to `å`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Oh, that could be it. I'm on a danish system, so there might be something there. Also, when replicating 11 times, I get 10 a's and one b.

Comment: @torbonde  Ok, please, the last try: select cast( replicate(char(97), 10) as varbinary(10)),
       replace (replicate(char(97), 10), 'a', 'b'), 
       cast( replace (replicate(char(97), 10), 'a', 'b') as varbinary(10))

Comment: @torbonde I was able to reproduce it and indeed the issue is the COLLATION. I updated my answer. I don't know how to ask to not put it on hold