# SQL LIKE operator with aaa% having strange behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my case I have patient table with few columns including patient's firstname and lastname. Application using this table having patient search functionality with firstname and lastname.

Having some test data in table with lastname ended with few letters of consecutive 'a' like in below image

[image]

So when I run below simple query it having some strange result

```
select * from A_Patient where Firstname like 'aaa%'- **0 Row**
select * from A_Patient where Firstname like 'aaaa%'- **7 Row**
select * from A_Patient where Firstname like 'aaaaa%'- **1 Row**
select * from A_Patient where Firstname like 'aaaaaa%' - **3 Row**
select * from A_Patient where Firstname like 'aaaaaaa%' - **0 Row**
select * from A_Patient where Firstname like 'aaaaaaaa%' - **3 Row**
```

So when having 'a' is even number it result all result. but when it odd number of characters it returns only if having extract number of character matching. otherwise it return none. 
I changed letter 'a' to 'b' and 'c' tested but this behaviors was not found.

DataType of columns are nvarchar. Any idea why this strange behaviors happen?

Comment: What collation are you using? In Danish collation `aa` is a special character (a with a circle), that could explain this behaviour.

Comment: If you have `nvarchar` data type try with ` .. LIKE N'aaa%'`

Comment: @Zhorov this doesn't change result.

Comment: @HoneyBadger it is Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS.

Comment: Related: [SQL 'Like' operator and 'aa' with collation Danish Norwegian CI AS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1171510/1220550)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421471/why-replaceaaaaaaa-a-b-in-sql-function-does-not-replace-all-a-letter/46421540#46421540

Comment: Thanks @HoneyBadger and others I find out what problem is. behavior due to  Collation Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see this test case:

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
,   LastName NVARCHAR(255) COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS
)

INSERT @TestTable (LastName)
VALUES  (N'aa')
,       (N'aaa')
,       (N'aaaa')

SELECT  *
FROM    @TestTable AS TT
WHERE   TT.LastName LIKE N'aaa%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Without the `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS` you get the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: we have to use Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS collation. because we storing Norwegian characters.